# ¿Cómo pasar el modelo al controlador (Laravel, relaciones polimórficas)?

Tags: laravel, relaciones

Tengo una relación polimórfica entre owner, pet y photo, ya que owner y pet pueden tener una photo. Para poder insertar las photos creé un PhotoController con el método store(). El problema es que dicho método solo sirve para guadar photos relacionadas con el modelo owner, ¿cómo se haría para que pudiera guardar tanto photos relacionadas con el modelo owner y también con el modelo pet? ¿O no se puede hacer esto?

```
public function store(Request $request, $id)
{
    $request->validate([
        'photo' => 'required|image'
    ]);


    $photo = $request->file('photo')->store('public/images');
    $url = Storage::url($photo);

    $owner = Owner::findOrFail($id);

    $owner->photo()->create([
        'url' => $url
    ]);

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Comment: ¿Quieres que la misma foto se almacene para ambas entidades?, es que no termino de entender el problema

Comment: No, quiero que el mismo método me permita guardar fotos de Owner y de Pet. Como puedes ver, ese controlador solo permite guardar fotos de Owner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero debemos de saber que el modelo no existe como instancia, entonces usemos un string como parámetro, teniendo eso en cuenta.

Agregando al modelo como parámetro seria de esta manera.

```
public function store(Request $request, $id, $model)
{ ... }
```

Dentro de la función tendríamos algo como esto.

```
public function store(Request $request, $id, $model)
{
$request->validate([
    'photo' => 'required|image'
]);


$photo = $request->file('photo')->store('public/images');
$url = Storage::url($photo);

$modelo = $model::findOrFail($id);

$modelo->photo()->create([
    'url' => $url
]);

return redirect()->back();
```

}

Quedaria enviar `MyModel::class` como parámetro.

Comment: @BetaM creo que entendí distinto, que pueda usar la misma función en ambos, exactamente.

Answer (score 1):

Amigo no veo muy claro lo que propones.  Yo interpreto que tienes una relacion de owner con pet, y de owner con photo. Si es asi mediante owner puedes acceder a photo desde pet.
Para hacer lo que deseas tendrias que tener relacionada pet con photo y desde el metodo que publicas acceder al modelo pet y adicionar la photo, como mismo lo haces aqui:

```
  $owner = Owner::findOrFail($id);

  $owner->photo()->create([
    'url' => $url
  ]);
```

Pero esto seria solo si fuera dos fotos distintas una para la mascosta y otra para el owner. Te sugiero nos expliques mejor tu negocio y lo que deseas.

Seria asi lo ultimo que te propongo.
en tus rutas:

```
 Route::post('/turutaPet', 'PhotController@store')->name('pet');
 Route::post('/turutaOwn', 'PhotController@store')->name('own');
```

en tu controlador:

```
    if(Route::currentRouteName() == 'pet'){
        $model = Pet::findOrFail($id);
    }
    else if(Route::currentRouteName() == 'owner')){
        $model = Owner::findOrFail($id);
    }
```

Comment: Perdón si no he sido claro. Tanto Owner como Pet, tienen una Photo (algo así como una foto de perfil), por ello estoy utilizando una relación polimórfica que permitirá guardar, en la misma tabla, tanto las fotografías correspondientes a las mascotas como las correspondientes a los propietarios. Entonces, estoy buscando cómo hacer un controlador que permita guardar tanto las fotos de las mascotas como de los propietarios (por ejemplo, dependiendo si le paso como parámetro un $Owner o si le paso un $Pet)

Comment: @BetaM no, solo se debe insertar a la mascota o al propietario en cuestión. Es decir, si estoy en el formulario para agregar una foto para el propietario, solo deberá insertarse para el propietario. Si estoy en el formulario de la mascota, solo deberá insertarse para la mascota.

Comment: quizas puedas asignarle a las rutas pet y owner dos nombres distintos. Las dos rutas aputan a las misma controladora@metodo. Ya en el metodo preguntas por el nombre de la ruta actual y en dependencia de cual sea declaras la variable $model con el modelo correspondiente. no lo pasarias por parametro al metodo pero igual realizarias la tarea.

Comment: edite la respuesta con la ultima propuesta.

Answer (score 1):

Considera lo siguiente:

- Podemos usar `findOrFail()` por cada modelo para identificar si el `id` retorna algún registro.
- Dentro de un condicional verificamos si los objetos donde hacemos las consultas anteriores no están vacíos
- En caso de que alguno esté vacío indica que el registro no existe y evalúa una siguiente condición, para que en consecuencia haga el `create`donde corresponde

Propuesta:

```
$owner = Owner::findOrFail($id);
$pet   = Pet::findOrFail($id);


if (!empty($owner)) {
    $owner->photo()->create([.................]);
} else if (!empty($pet)) {
    $pet->photo()->create([..................]);
}
```

Como estamos usando el método `findOrFail` si no obtenemos un registro como respuesta entonces veremos en pantalla un error 404 indicando que no fue localizado un valor asociado a dicho id.

**Edición**

Con base en tu [comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/392475/c%c3%b3mo-pasar-el-modelo-al-controlador-laravel-relaciones-polim%c3%b3rficas/392493?noredirect=1#comment702965_392493) puedes tener otra aproximación basándote en:

- Tener un input de tipo `hidden` con un nombre que aluda a identificar en que formulario se encuentra
- Cuando recibas el `request` evaluarás si el valor esta presente (*con ayuda del método `has`*) y dependiendo de lo que recibas entonces construyes un condicional para efectuar el alta
- Ya dentro del alta efectúas nuevamente la búsqueda del registro en alguno de los modelos

Propuesta:

En tu formulario de Owners:

```
<input type="hidden" name="owner_form" />
```

En tu formulario de Pets:

```
<input type="hidden" name="pet_form" />
```

Finalmente en el controlador:

```
        if ($request->has('ower_form')) {
            $owner = Ower::findOrFail($id);
            $owner->photo()->create([.................]);
        } else if($request->has('pet_form')) {
            $pet = Pet::findOrFail($id);
            $pet->photo()->create([................]);
        } else {
            return 'El recurso no puede generar un alta al sistema';
        }
```

**Referencias**

- [input hidden](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/input/hidden)
- [Método has](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#input-trimming-and-normalization)
- [Método empty](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.empty.php)
- [Método findOrFail](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#retrieving-single-models)